# How to configure twilio to validate PIN entered by user?

Tags: c#, ajax, twilio, twilio-api

I have some reply options configured based on what user chooses once Twilio number is called,
Willing to know how do i configure such a logic to check if pin entered entered by user to speak to agent is valid or not,
If not valid some fallback reply should be sent ideally,
otherwise call should reach out and gets connected to customer care executive !

Environment i am using:

1) **C#** - to handle Twilio Service calls.

2) **Sql-Server** = to manage replies based on options chose by user !

NOTE: If the question or scenario is unclear or needs some code samples, Please leave a comment before down-voting !

Help Appreciated !

Comment: Is **verify** a way to go for this https://www.twilio.com/console/verify/getting-started/build ?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather